# llblgen: How do i filter?

Tags: asp.net, llblgenpro

Im having some problems with filtering data with LLBLGen. I have an EmployeeEntity where i want to fetch the data filtering by string CustomerNumber. CustomerNumber is not Primary Key. I guess i have to use the IPredicateExpression, but how?

EDIT: Im using the Adapter Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
IRelationPredicateBucket bucket = new RelationPredicateBucket();
bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(EmployeeFields.CustomerNumber == "123");
```

You can find a much more in-depth discussion [here](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/gencode_paging_adapter.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
EmployeeCollection employees = new EmployeeCollection();
employees.GetMulti(EmployeeFields.CustomerNumber == "123");
```

Comment: Which namespace should i include to get the GetMulti function?

Comment: GetMulti() is a method of the CollectionClasses.EmployeeCollection object. This example is using LLBLGen's Self Service model, so if you're using the Adapter model then the solution will be different.

Comment: im using the Adapter Model. Can you give an example with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch lists using `DataAccessAdapter.FetchEntities`. The filtering can be done via PredicateExpressions. A nice documentation of the predicate system can be found [here](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/Filtering%20and%20Sorting/gencode_filteringpredicateclasses_adapter.htm).